# MQL4 how can I check if the order hit SL?

Tags: mql4, mql

I am coding an algorithmic trading robot and how can I check if the order hit SL on MQL4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most robust method is to record then track the trade using its [OrderTicket()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/orderticket). Track this until the trade is closed (using [OrderCloseTime()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/orderclosetime) to determine when closed). You can then retrieve the [OrderClosePrice()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordercloseprice) and check it against the [OrderStopLoss()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/orderstoploss).

Comment: But I'm getting a weird error. It gives me the closing price even though I asked for the order open price. `if(OrderSelect(Ticket[0],SELECT_BY_TICKET) == true)
      {
         Print("Order Open Price = " + OrderOpenPrice());
         Print("Order Close Price = " + OrderClosePrice());
         Print("Order Stop Loss Price = " + OrderStopLoss());
      }`  Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is a separate question to the one asked. I would suggest marking this answer as accepted and posting a new question with your full code.

Answer (score 0):

**For MQL5**

**If trade hit stoploss or target then it will close automatically
You just need to check position of that symbol.**

```
 if(!PositionSelect(_Symbol))
     {
      // trade is closed, now you can take new entry of that symbol.
     }
```

Comment: The question is specifically relating to MQL4. MQL5 is a different programming language and your answer therefore does not address the question.